# Is this a bad pattern use Map() as react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I'm building a component that saves in his state the selected items. I can use a array for this, but for search it'll be O(n). This is not a big issue because it's a few items. But I was thinking of use [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)  to search the items in O(1). Is this a bad pattern? Should I use a array or something else? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Is this a bad pattern?` No. I dont think so.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad pattern. However I do think if you're expecting literally any performance improvement you'll be disappointed.

Comment: Can you explain me why @arthurakay please?

Comment: Simply because of the small data size. You're right about the theoretical improvement, but in a browser-based JavaScript application you realistically won't have enough data in the state to show any noticeable difference.

Comment: It's makes complete sense, thank you very much @arthurakay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bad pattern. Just be aware of create a new Map when you add or delete some item before update the state.